# Total Chern Class of Hodge Bundle via CohFT

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, gromov-witten-theory

I am interested in the calculation of total Chern class of Hodge bundle. I am aware that there is a way by the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch formula, however, I read that this is also a cohomological field theory. I did not know how to produce the R-matrix for this case. Is there any hint or reference for this?

Answer (score 3):

A reference would be Pandharipande's ICM address [*Cohomological field theory calculations*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.02528), section 1.3. The $R$-matrix is
$$
R(z)=\exp\bigg(-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{2k(2k-1)}z^{2k-1}\bigg).
$$